# extracting attribute values which might have multiple occurences from xml file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

Updating the thread.
I need help in extracting some information from xml file using perl.

1) test.xml file

How can I extract hostname1.xxx.com(hostname) and key and tier and then put it in one file ( a text file ) using perl scripts

**Contents:**

```
<httpsRoutes>
    <httpsRoute hostname="hostname1.xxx.com" port="443" environment="QA" tier="dmz">
            <key>6924</key>
    </httpsRoute>
    <httpsRoute hostname="hostname3.xxx.com" port="7416" environment="CAT" tier="dmz">
            <key>9990068</key>
    </httpsRoute>
</httpsRoutes>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!.

Comment: It is unreasonable to ask for a full sourcecode for a program that you need to write. There are a lot of people who are willing to help you with specific questions or problems that you have, but not to do all of the work for you.

Comment: apologies.
I'm new to perl stuff, Just trying to be clear.
I'll try to get the pointers for the experts to get on going. Thank you!.

Comment: Updated the thread kindly help!.

Comment: Any pointers would be really helpful. Thank you in advance!.